# Dynamic filter in clarity design

Tags: angular, typescript, vmware-clarity, clarity, proclarity

[image]I am new to clarity design framework. I have created the customized grid with dynamic column and dynamic row in Clarity design. I am trying to filter as based on the dynamic column but I am not able to get the column name in the default filter provided by Clarity instead it is getting the response data

Comment: Hey there. I’m happy to try and help with your question. It’s hard to say what you should do without an isolated example of what your are trying to do. If you could create a small isolated example with the code your are trying I can look at it. We keep starter stackblitzes here: https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @hippeelee said, it is easier with a stackblitz. But, as far as I understood, you want to use the datagrids column filtering. For the column based filtering you need to use the [Smart Iterator](https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/smart-iterator). I am not quite sure, but it seems that you use `ngFor` instead of  `clrDgItems` for the row loop.

Comment: If the answer was part of the solution would you mind to accept the answer for further references